# XML - Extract after a String and before a certain character

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, substring

I've the following XML Code:

```
_RCFM*=.·<form><text id="NomeTransporteSAP" label="JOB: *" mandatory="true" multiline="true" readonly="false" visible="true">AA123EDC/NB: Cheque holding v05  TESTE PT 223427</text>
```

I'm trying to create a statement that allows me to get the ID: AA123EDC

For that I'm using:

```
SUBSTRING(col1, LEN(SUBSTRING(col1, 0, LEN(col1) - CHARINDEX ('DSI Request Number', col1))) + 1, 
            LEN(col1) - LEN(SUBSTRING(col1, 0, LEN(col1) - CHARINDEX ('DSI Request Number', col1))) 
            - LEN(SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX ('</text><text id=', col1), LEN(col1))))
```

But it gives me the wrong string...

Anybody can give me a help?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the error occured

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.

Comment: This error is caused by passing a negative value to the length parameter of the SUBSTRING, LEFT and RIGHT string functions. To avoid this error, always make sure that you pass a non-negative value to the length parameter of the SUBSTRING, LEFT and RIGHT functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is quite unclear (but you've tagged it with `tsql`...). It seems that you want to read a value form within an XML. Furthermore this value is not atomic, so you have to parse it out.

If my assumptions are correct, you should try it this way:

```
DECLARE @YourXML XML=
N'<form>
  <text id="NomeTransporteSAP" label="JOB: *" mandatory="true" multiline="true" readonly="false" visible="true">AA123EDC/NB: Cheque holding v05  TESTE PT 223427</text>
</form>';

WITH ReadFromXML AS
(
    SELECT @YourXML.value(N'(/form/text/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS TheValue --AA123EDC/NB: Cheque holding v05  TESTE PT 223427
)
SELECT LEFT(TheValue,CHARINDEX('/',TheValue)-1)
FROM ReadFromXML;
```

This will use a CTE to retrieve the inner text in a derived table and cut away everything starting with the `/` using `LEFT`.

The CTE-approach is not necessary, but is much better to read.

If your XML is living within a table you can use the same approach, but in this case I'd use `CROSS APPLY` instead of the CTE.